# Flutter isar web - Unique index violated, even with using replaceOnConflict

Tags: flutter, flutter-isar

With Flutter project, I am using Isar for local storage

In Isar collection, I am using `@Index(unique: true)`

In Isar put I am using `replaceOnConflict: true`

In **Web**, for first insert it runs fine. But for **2nd insert with same value of index, it gives error**.

I was expecting it to replace old record with same index in web also.

**In Android, its running as expected** and replacing previous record if new record with same value of index is inserted

**Here is collection in my_product.dart**

```html
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';

part 'my_product.g.dart';

@Collection()
class MyProduct {
  @Id()
  int? id;

  @Index(unique: true)
  String? prodId;

  String? name;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "($id / $prodId / $name)";
  }
}
```

**product object:**

```
{
    prodId: 'prod1'
    name: 'product One'
}
```

**Putting same product object twice** in isar.

Here is **code to put new record in Isar**

```html
await isarProdDetails.writeTxn((isar) async {
    insertedId = await isar.myProducts.put(
        product,
        replaceOnConflict: true,
    );
});
```

Both inserts work fine in Android

In Web, first insert works fine.
**For 2nd insert**, getting below **error in web.**

```
Error: IsarError: Unique index violated
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:56430/dart_sdk.js:5080:11)
at isar_impl.IsarImpl.new._txn (http://localhost:56430/packages/isar/src/web/open.dart.lib.js:855:27)
    at _txn.throw (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:56430/dart_sdk.js:40646:38
    at _RootZone.runBinary (http://localhost:56430/dart_sdk.js:40515:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleError (http://localhost:56430/dart_sdk.js:35449:33)
    at handleError (http://localhost:56430/dart_sdk.js:36015:51)
    at _Future._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:56430/dart_sdk.js:36041:17)
    at [_completeError] (http://localhost:56430/dart_sdk.js:35878:23)
    at http://localhost:56430/dart_sdk.js:35927:31
    at _rootRun (http://localhost:56430/dart_sdk.js:40931:14)
    at async._CustomZone.new.run (http://localhost:56430/dart_sdk.js:40178:14)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:56430/dart_sdk.js:40128:33)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:56430/dart_sdk.js:40778:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:56430/dart_sdk.js:40784:13)
    at http://localhost:56430/dart_sdk.js:36261:9
```

Using below library versions in pubsec.yaml

```
  isar: ^2.5.0
  isar_flutter_libs: ^2.5.0
```

Using **Flutter 3.0.5**

Comment: Opened an issue https://github.com/isar/isar/issues/574